# The Clock Speed for the Quantum Computers

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization

Is there a way to look up the clock speed for the different computers?

Answer (score 4):

The clock time (speed) for a quantum computer would be related to the T1 relaxation times (1/T1 rate) of the specific qubits and their architecture. The T1 relaxation time is essentially the time it takes for the qubit to return to an equilibrium and to be in the position to re-initialize.

While T2 and the gate time tells you how many operations you can perform in the given T1 clock cycle.

Comment: Do you mean that a frequency is related to T1 through formula $f=\frac{1}{T1}$?